# How to get the href from an <a> tag inside a <div> by text using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
text = """<div class="content">
   <div class="body">
    <img src="https:/document-images/leasing/mynd-logo.png" alt="j0b" width="96px" height="auto" class="kjhjhv">
    <div class="title">
      You've received a new message.
     <div class="subtitle">
      Service request <a href="https://-2B06XEJ0r8DVmc_kuX2cI8baDAaOcj-2Fp3iIjU6R7PXKa3dAYAr0B7iMyKwz-2FaV0nnIuCVP1pcf8DEy1UidQbR2IywCV5ueXy1TowXMzFcIPYG2hp7HjP1WzHYI-2FJNMGLZMtC4LXybcCZ4cUOV4DnC6s-2FCIJ-2FrumGmdnE2leBJgM3rWJaEyXOwi4JiHjBHr4rtNh-2BPeP3JFBHpGNp5KWrZkxg-2F9zrih4tp7-2BUUrBo0g8hlG5It1yEVfz9Im2iRVAvdjqHvAqxn63TsV2OFNp8M8DMjuS6aRL3Vki8HfkXx0kD8fGJ6GAKUAOZv-2BCSAgxtcdnIpR8sQU6Jkcm9vxdjG2zmDYFEmVykg0-2BY3uD1ZbGl79dsB68mqJdbbQlgb8ERSRAW3t8cYTXsegrGd5-2Fox-2B9Yo-2FPmUC9cnqEaA-3D-3D" style="color:#5A88AA; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank">#2819138</a>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- CONTENT OF EMAIL -->
    <p> May 17, 2023 05:33 PDT <b> Charisse </b> wrote: </p>
    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Hi team. Is this completed? Please advise. Thank you, Charisse</p>
   </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
scores = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Service request'))
print(scores)
score2 = soup.find('div',text=re.compile('Service request'))
print(score2)
```

My required answer:

> https://-2B06XEJ0r8DVmc_kuX2cI8baDAaOcj-2Fp3iIjU6R7PXKa3dAYAr0B7iMyKwz-2FaV0nnIuCVP1pcf8DEy1UidQbR2IywCV5ueXy1TowXMzFcIPYG2hp7HjP1WzHYI-2FJNMGLZMtC4LXybcCZ4cUOV4DnC6s-2FCIJ-2FrumGmdnE2leBJgM3rWJaEyXOwi4JiHjBHr4rtNh-2BPeP3JFBHpGNp5KWrZkxg-2F9zrih4tp7-2BUUrBo0g8hlG5It1yEVfz9Im2iRVAvdjqHvAqxn63TsV2OFNp8M8DMjuS6aRL3Vki8HfkXx0kD8fGJ6GAKUAOZv-2BCSAgxtcdnIpR8sQU6Jkcm9vxdjG2zmDYFEmVykg0-2BY3uD1ZbGl79dsB68mqJdbbQlgb8ERSRAW3t8cYTXsegrGd5-2Fox-2B9Yo-2FPmUC9cnqEaA-3D-3D

I need to get that URL using the text "Service request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML code you want to search for `<a>` tag where previous sibling is text node with `Service request` text:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<div class="content">
   <div class="body">
    <img src="https:/document-images/leasing/mynd-logo.png" alt="j0b" width="96px" height="auto" class="kjhjhv">
    <div class="title">
      You've received a new message.
     <div class="subtitle">
      Service request <a href="https://-2B06XEJ0r8DVmc_kuX2cI8baDAaOcj-2Fp3iIjU6R7PXKa3dAYAr0B7iMyKwz-2FaV0nnIuCVP1pcf8DEy1UidQbR2IywCV5ueXy1TowXMzFcIPYG2hp7HjP1WzHYI-2FJNMGLZMtC4LXybcCZ4cUOV4DnC6s-2FCIJ-2FrumGmdnE2leBJgM3rWJaEyXOwi4JiHjBHr4rtNh-2BPeP3JFBHpGNp5KWrZkxg-2F9zrih4tp7-2BUUrBo0g8hlG5It1yEVfz9Im2iRVAvdjqHvAqxn63TsV2OFNp8M8DMjuS6aRL3Vki8HfkXx0kD8fGJ6GAKUAOZv-2BCSAgxtcdnIpR8sQU6Jkcm9vxdjG2zmDYFEmVykg0-2BY3uD1ZbGl79dsB68mqJdbbQlgb8ERSRAW3t8cYTXsegrGd5-2Fox-2B9Yo-2FPmUC9cnqEaA-3D-3D" style="color:#5A88AA; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank">#2819138</a>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- CONTENT OF EMAIL -->
    <p> May 17, 2023 05:33 PDT <b> Charisse </b> wrote: </p>
    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Hi team. Is this completed? Please advise. Thank you, Charisse</p>
   </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

a = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "a"
    and tag.find_previous_sibling(string=re.compile("Service request"))
)
print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://-2B06XEJ0r8DVmc_kuX2cI8baDAaOcj-2Fp3iIjU6R7PXKa3dAYAr0B7iMyKwz-2FaV0nnIuCVP1pcf8DEy1UidQbR2IywCV5ueXy1TowXMzFcIPYG2hp7HjP1WzHYI-2FJNMGLZMtC4LXybcCZ4cUOV4DnC6s-2FCIJ-2FrumGmdnE2leBJgM3rWJaEyXOwi4JiHjBHr4rtNh-2BPeP3JFBHpGNp5KWrZkxg-2F9zrih4tp7-2BUUrBo0g8hlG5It1yEVfz9Im2iRVAvdjqHvAqxn63TsV2OFNp8M8DMjuS6aRL3Vki8HfkXx0kD8fGJ6GAKUAOZv-2BCSAgxtcdnIpR8sQU6Jkcm9vxdjG2zmDYFEmVykg0-2BY3uD1ZbGl79dsB68mqJdbbQlgb8ERSRAW3t8cYTXsegrGd5-2Fox-2B9Yo-2FPmUC9cnqEaA-3D-3D
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.select_one("a", text='Service request')['href']
```

Comment: Thanks for support. This solution is ok. Is there any solution to get div and get the href

Comment: That doesn't work. `.select_one` doesn't have `text=` attribute. This simply finds first `<a>` tag

Comment: @AndrejKesely does work for me, so maybe depends on version.

Comment: @GedasMiksenas It "works" because it select the first `<a>` tag in the HTML (which happens to be the correct one in this case). The text= parameter is ignored.

Comment: @BenDavid sure thing: soup.find('div', class_ = 'subtitle').a['href']

Comment: @AndrejKesely oh right, you are correct.